# Django/Pillow ImageField - image not showing

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to follow along to a Codemy Youtube tutorial and I am not having the same results. I want to display an image on a Django website. I have installed Pillow correctly and followed the tutorial step by step but I am only getting a broken image icon on the webpage.

Copied image url from broken img icon - http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/MX1A1063.JPG

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51HgB.png - settings.py
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMy0F.png - Broken img icon
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg55Z.png - forms.py
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYeGm.png - terminal window
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UhvU.png - pip freeze
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QzGR.png - models.py
[7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKHxF.png - product_detail.html
[8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyzDy.png - images folder in main src folder

Tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygzGr51dbsY&ab_channel=Codemy.com

Comment: hi, it will be better if you paste code in the post rather than as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, but I have just realised all along that it is because I had MEDIA_ROOT = [BASE_DIR / 'media'], instead of MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media', making it a list instead of a string.

It's always something minor like this. Thanks all for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

you may missed url suffix

like this:

```
{{ context.image.url }}
```

last url suffix is important